# Rotate server IPs using selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, web-scraping

I'm working on a project where i need to scrap some data using selenium.. For scrapping, i want to rotate my server IPs (my server has multiple IPs attached to single machine). For each request, i want to use a different IP so i don't get blocked. Not sure how this could be done. I'm using Firefox on ubuntu 16.04.

So far, by googling for many hours, i have found this but its not working.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", 'my-ip')
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 80)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.https", 'my-ip')
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.https_port", 80)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('https://api.ipify.org/')
print driver.page_source
```

I'm testing with https://api.ipify.org/ just to find which IP is used for the generated request but it always shows me the primary IP of my server even though i have set different IP using the above code.

Any help/guidance or workaround would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would need is to bind Firefox to a different network interface, which is not possible.

A workaround would be to set up a proxy like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org) on your server, configure it to route outgoing traffic through each interface based on a parameter you can control from selenium configuration for Firefox, for example the proxy port (it should be possible with squid acl).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using squid